# Android app not showing up in market

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded my app and clicked publish 3 hours ago.

My android publisher page says "This application is available to over 301 devices. Show devices"

I checked from a browser and it's not in the market.  My phone is listed in the shown devices.  I checked on my phone and it's not there either.

The app is marked as published on my developer home page.

Also there's no logo next to my app on my page with the app.  I have both an icon in the apk and a high resolution graphic.

Comment: They changed the developer console recently. Now you can activate/deactivate different versions of your app, maybe even if it says "published" at the top of the screen. But the fact that your app's icon is not showing is odd.  The icon that's shown next to your app in the list on the developer console is not the one that you individually upload. It's the one that's inside your apk and associated with the <application> element's android:icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the direct link ? `https://market.android.com/details?id=PACKAGE_NAME` If this link works, give it some more time.